# CNN(s) for dimensions and direction

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have thousands of images with vehicles labeled with length, width, and direction/front. Are there any pre-built CNNs for multi-label (3 or 4) training?

I'm terrible with python, but learning. I've adapted code for YOLOv7 and a few other pre-built networks for just category classification. If no pre-existing networks exist, how hard would it be to add multi-label to a ResNet type network? Thanks.